# Need an explanation on how this code works

Tags: c

I'm learning C in college and I don't understand this piece of code that my professor wrote and it has no explanation (I know it adds a random number from 0 to 99 to next array element but don't know how)

```
srandom(time(NULL));

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = i == 0 ? random() % 100 : a[i-1] + random() % 100;
```

Though it works as intended, I would just like to understand how it adds numbers to next array element without "+=" or something like that.

Comment: Where do you see a `+=`?

Comment: It's using `a[i-1]` to access the previous array element, to which it adds a new random number, storing the result in the next array element.

Comment: This is pretty bad form for a learner in collage.  Was your tutor trying to make himself look superior with his great skills ?

Comment: He's expecting a `+=` because he sees a value summed with another. It's the `a[i-1]+random()%100` part to make it confounded, I think

Comment: What might be throwing you off is the use of a [conditional operator](http://www.trytoprogram.com/c-programming/c-conditional-operator/),  a[i] is being assigned to either a random number or a[i - 1] + a random number depending on whether or not i is 0.

Comment: @Neil Behold the sophistication :)

Answer (score 6):

You can rewrite it like this:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        a[i] = random()%100;
    } else {
        a[i] = a[i-1] + random()%100;
    }
}
```

So, you see that the value at `a[1]` is `a[0] + random()%100` and so on. The `if` is needed because when `i` is 0, you haven't a previous values to use (`a[-1]` would be an error). The ternary operator `condition ? a : b` can be read as "if condition is true, a; else b".

Comment: And you could eliminate the if statement completely by assigning to a[0] outside the loop and starting the loop from 1.

Comment: Of course. You should also not write `random()%100`, and so on. This translates what he has written without trying to make it better than it is, just replacing the ternary in the hope it makes what the original code does clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it on this way:

```
srandom(time(NULL));

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (i == 0){
        a[i] = random() % 100; // random number module 100 will give number between 0 and 99 inclusive
    }
    else{
        a[i] = a[i - 1] + random() % 100; // a[i] will get value equal to sum of previous array value a[i - 1] and new random number between 0 and 99
    }
}
```

In for loop you have i++ which is increasing index by one.

Comment: THIS is what your tutor should be showing you.  Clear, concise and doesn't need explaining too much to learners.